# stop/start live wallpaper service

Tags: android, live-wallpaper

how can i stop and start live wallpaper service in android programmatically ?

this code help me to send user for select my live wallpaper from list

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 15)
        {
            i.setAction(WallpaperManager.ACTION_CHANGE_LIVE_WALLPAPER);
            String pkg = WallpaperService.class.getPackage().getName();
            String cls = WallpaperService.class.getCanonicalName();
            i.putExtra(WallpaperManager.EXTRA_LIVE_WALLPAPER_COMPONENT, new ComponentName(pkg, cls));
        }
        else
        {
            i.setAction(WallpaperManager.ACTION_LIVE_WALLPAPER_CHOOSER);
        }
        startActivityForResult(i, 0);
```

is there any way to programmatically change the user's live wallpaper ?

Comment: Did you get to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

If your are using a test device that have API level below the 15 it will not be possible to change live wallpaper the way you want.! Your code is perfectly alright. Just test on a device that have API level greater then 15/16.!

Comment: so, how to stop?